# QDockWidget make left side longer instead of bottom

Tags: qt, qdockwidget

I'm using `QDockWidget` on the left and bottom of my UI. But no matter in which order I set them, the bottom one will always cut off the left one.

[image]

Is there a way to get the left docker extended to the bottom?

Comment: I think you're looking for [`QMainWindow::setCorner`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCorner).

Comment: Fantastic, exactly what I needed! Could you put it as an answer then I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comment you can make use of [`QMainWindow::setCorner`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCorner) to assign a corner to a particular dock area.  In your case you need...

```
setCorner(Qt::BottomLeftCorner, Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea);
```

Comment: For PyQt5 users:

`from PyQt5 import QtCore`

 and `mainWindow.setCorner( QtCore.Qt.BottomLeftCorner, QtCore.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea )`